# Summary reports using solr

Tags: solr

I need to build reports using solr (even though solr is search tool) is it possible to get an equivalent result from solr using
**stats, group by and pivot**. Or do I need to use nosql something like MongoDB?

```
select field1,field2,count(*) from TABLE1 group by field1,field2




select field1,max(field2),min(field2),count(field1),max(field3),sum(field4) from TABLE1 group by field1
```

I can achieve group wise stats when there is only one field in a group, not able to achieve the same when I want to group by for more than one field

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about the [JSON Facet API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/json-facet-api.html) ?

Comment: MatsLindh, Thanks for the reply.
I am using SOLR 4, is it possible with this version or do I need to upgrade solr?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend upgrading (for many other reasons as well). You  might be able to work around it with `facet.pivot`, the `stats` endpoint, etc., but it will be a lot harder. A more recent version of Solr will also allow you to write Streaming Expressions, which are well suited for any sort of analytics.

Comment: @MatsLindh OK, Thank You!